# vmstat -m -> pages less than total?

Tags: linux, command

When I type vmstat -m in command line, it shows:

```
Cache                       Num  Total   Size  Pages
fuse_request                  0      0    424      9
fuse_inode                    0      0    768      5
pid_2                         0      0    128     30
nfs_direct_cache              0      0    200     19
nfs_commit_data               0      0    704     11
nfs_write_data               36     36    960      4
nfs_read_data                 0      0    896      4
nfs_inode_cache            8224   8265   1048      3
nfs_page                      0      0    128     30
fscache_cookie_jar            2     48     80     48
rpc_buffers                   8      8   2048      2
rpc_tasks                     8     15    256     15
rpc_inode_cache              17     24    832      4
bridge_fdb_cache             14     59     64     59
nf_conntrack_expect           0      0    240     16
```

For the nfs_write_data line(line 7), why the "pages" is less than "total"?

For some of them, the "total" is always equal to "pages".

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [vmstat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vmstat)

> ...
>   The **-m** switch displays slabinfo. 
>   ...
>   **Field Description For Slab Mode**
>   **cache**: Cache name
>   **num**: Number of currently active objects
>   **total**: Total number of available objects
>   **size**: Size of each object
>   **pages**: Number of pages with at least one active object
>   **totpages**: Total number of allocated pages
>   **pslab**: Number of pages per slab

Thus, **total** is the number of slabinfo objects (objects used by the OS as inodes, buffers and so on) and a **page** can contain more than one object

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You can see this line:nfs_inode_cache            8224   8265   1048      3.  "size" is the largest, while "pages" is small. I don't know the reason.

Comment: You should interpret that line as: There is a total number of 8265 objects of type "inode" in memory from which 8224 are considered "active". Each object of type inode occupes 1048 bytes. All those inode objects are stored in 3 pages